# Would the fringe spacing be the same if the slits were at different positions in Youngs double slit experiment?

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment

If the experiment was set up as shown in the image below, where the two slits are at different distances from the screen,

[image]

would the fringe spacing still be
y = ($\lambda)*L/d$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light, $d$ is the slit spacing (along the y-axis) and $L$ is the distance from the furthest slit to the screen?
If not, what would the fringe spacing equation now be?

Comment: Double of your previous Q but you got a better A :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is equivalent to set your screen slightly rotated an angle $\alpha$ (see the figure below).

If your spacing is $a$, then your new spacing with the rotated screen would be $a' = a \cos \alpha$.

[image]

Edit: You can take the approximation $\cos \alpha \approx 1 - \frac{\alpha^2}{2}$, which is valid for $\alpha \ll 1$. You can see that there isn't any first-order term, so this means that if you have small enough angles the $\alpha^2$ term is negligible. This proves that, at first order approximation, the spacing would be the same, but this is only true if $\alpha$ is small enough. This is the situation when the two slits are almost aligned. This justifies S. McGrew's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Offsetting one of the slits in the direction of L by a small amount just shifts the fringe positions, without affecting fringe spacing.

Comment: is there any way to show this mathematically?

Comment: I edited my answer, I show S. McGrew's answer mathematically.